# Could the Elder Wand be repaired and used again?

Tags: harry-potter, deathly-hallows

At the very end of *Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows* movie, Harry broke the Elder Wand and threw away the pieces. Did the Elder Wand lose its power permanently due to this? Or could someone repair it with a "Reparo" spell and use it again?

Comment: As others noted, it was NOT broken in the book. As far as someone else possibly using it, it was discussed here: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/12593/was-harry-making-a-big-mistake-with-his-plan-for-elder-wand

Comment: I think this may be a possible duplicate: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/4805/why-did-harry-potter-break-the-elder-wand   (not VTCing yet as I'm not sure)

Comment: @DVK No, its not a duplicate. That question is trying to invade Harry's mind, but this one has nothing to do with that.

Comment: To really get the answer to this question, you'd have to ask the director what was going through his head.  If you get a chance to do that, there are about a dozen other scenes in that movie I'd like to ask him about...

Comment: @Kyralessa I was hoping to find answer from already existing book rollouts etc.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Harry broke the wand in *Deathly Hallows - Part Two* the movie. This is not what happened in canon.

In the book, Harry uses the Elder Wand to heal/mend his broken holly/phoenix feather wand. He then discusses the wand with Dumbledore and plans to return the wand to Dumbledore's tomb. This makes the wand vulnerable to theft. It is my guess that the Elder Wand is immune to Reparo and other basic spells like that.

So, yes, the Elder Wand could return to service again if someone stole it and began using it, or if Harry began using it.

If Harry dies a natural death, the power of the Elder Wand will be broken, as Harry, the wand's last owner, would have never lost the wand to defeat in a dual or by being disarmed.

Comment: Ah, but what if someone disarms Harry in his career as an Auror? Would the wand's allegence then pass to that person?

Comment: @JackBNimble The best (and only good) explanation I've heard for that issue is that someone will disarm Harry. And then someone will disarm the new person, and then someone else, and then someonelse, and pretty soon no one will have any idea who the master of the wand is.   But ya, Harry's reasoning he can die and the wand will lose it's power seems pretty silly =)

Comment: its also not clear how many people actually know about the Elder Wand, who its owner is, where it is, etc. Security by obscurity *always works*...

Comment: ...yes, because security by obscurity worked so well the first time - in the matter of both Horcruxes and the elder wand :\

Comment: @KutuluMike Harry told all those in the final stand that he was the owner. I do think though that your comment wasn't meant seriously. I will say though that security through obscurity works but only in combination with other layers (and to those who disagree and say that it is never useful: I ask them to hand over all their financial information, identification, keys etc. - and of course passwords).

Answer (score 8):

First, in the book, the wand was intact when it went into the tomb.

Second, one cannot simply steal the Elder Wand and use its full power. For someone to take it and have complete access to its near limitless power, they would first need to defeat Harry to earn the wands loyalty, otherwise, the wand's potential is equivalent to a common wand. Harry's [plan](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Elder_Wand#Harry.27s_decision) was for the wand's power to be destroyed once he naturally dies and the wands loyalty is unable to pass to another.

> "I'm putting the Elder Wand back where it came from. It can stay there. If I die a natural death like [Ignotus](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Ignotus_Peverell), its power will be broken, won't it? The previous master will never have been defeated. That'll be the end of it."

Comment: Another person can simply use the Elder Wand without being master of it. It will just not work as effectively as if its master were handling it and -- at least canon implies -- it won't work against its true master. Voldemort used the Elder Wand to great effect, even though first Draco then Harry was the wand's masters. But he wasn't able to master it fully. Using the wand is one thing. Mastering it is entirely another.

Comment: But in that scenario, it's just another wand, not the Elder Wand.

Comment: Would they just have to defeat Harry, or would they have to defeat him while he is wielding the Elder Wand?

Comment: @PoloHoleSet given that Malfoy wasn't wielding the Elder Wand when Harry force-took the bunch of wands from him, we can be sure any defeat of Harry will transfer the allegiance of the Elder Wand.

Comment: @Ruslan - Good point.

Answer (score 3):

If you think of Hagrid's wand, than you will know that in most cases wands cannot be repaired by magic (only the elder wand can repair wands), but it may still be useful like Hagrid's umbrella.

Answer (score 1):

*No*. Hermione could not fix Harry's broken wand and even Ollivander said it could not be fixed. The only wand that is known to be able to fix a wand is The Elder Wand itself but that is kind of the problem because it is the Elder Wand that is broken.

> “Yes,” said Harry. “Can you — ?”
>
> “No,” whispered Ollivander. “I am sorry, very sorry, but a wand that has suffered this degree of damage cannot be repaired by any means that I know of.”

Comment: Do you have a quote when Ollivander says this? I don't remember hearing or seeing that, thanks :)

Comment: Yes of course but in 10 days time because I am on a school vacation right now and my book is in another country

Comment: well I wish you a pleasant vacation!